# Why don't I need to write property at object class in sealed class by Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm developing the app by using Kotlin.

```
sealed class DestinationScreen(val route:String){
    object Signup: DestinationScreen(route = "signup")
}

@Composable
fun InstagramApp(){
 
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = DestinationScreen.Signup.route){
        composable(DestinationScreen.Signup.route){
            SignupScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know Why Signup singleton class can have the property "route" using argv?
I understand it inherits DestinationScreen. So it also has route property.

But Destination class doesn't have concrete the property `route`.
If Destination class is data class, make sense it doesn't need to declare the property.
No need for`{}`. And data class has the property not declareing it by using argv.
So I mean DestinationScreen should has concrete property `route`, if Signup inherit different property's value, it should override.
Why can this codes above work? Does this feature have seal class or object class?

Please teach me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Destination class doesn't have concrete the property `route`

Yes, it does. The `route` property is declared right there in its constructor.

> if Signup inherit different property's value, it should override

Not sure what you mean by this, but Signup doesn't need to override the property. It already inherits the property. By passing a value to the super-class's constructor, the existing property gets an initial value as passed by the sub-class without overriding it.

You mention `sealed` and `data` class types, but they are irrelevant to this discussion. Inheritance works the same way with sealed and non-sealed classes.

Any time a class extends another class, it also **is** a type of that class and inherits all of its properties and functions, no overriding needed.

Comment: Hi, Tenfour. Thank you for teaching me. So do you mean even if any class doesn't declare  its constructor, can it has the same property name as argv? I mean Destination class should declare constructor, and set property. But no need for this.
Please answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "argv", or what you mean by "But no need for this". Every class has a constructor. If you don't explicitly define it, it still has an implicit one with zero arguments.

Comment: I mean DestinationScreen class doesn't have clear constructor, but in fact it has the property `route`.  I think DestinationScreen get the argument of the name 'route ', and if using the value of the argument in DestinationScreen class, it should have `self.route = route`.  Your explanation is no need for obvious constructor. And DestinationScreen class has the property of  argument's name. right?   Please tell me about such things. Thank you.

Comment: DestinationScreen does have a clear constructor. Anything in parentheses `()` after the name of a class is its primary constructor. DestinationScreen's constructor is `(val route:String)`. `route` is a parameter of the DestinationScreen constructor, and it is also a property. When you put properties in a constructor, they are also constructor parameters. This is a feature of all classes, not just data classes. If you define your property in the braces `{}`, then it is not a constructor parameter.